# Clearing Inner Float

Tags: html, css

I'm developing a web page that has an outer floated left column and a regular right column.

The right column then contains a list of items where each item has a floated left column and a regular right column.

My problem is when a list item's right column isn't tall enough, the next list item is indented to be to the right of the previous item's left column.

Convoluted? Okay, well I've [posted the basic layout online](http://jsfiddle.net/scwebgroup/bae2j).

I then removed items from a sublist so that [one list item's right column isn't tall enough](http://jsfiddle.net/scwebgroup/bae2j/1/).

Finally, I tried [correcting the problem using `clear:both`](http://jsfiddle.net/scwebgroup/bae2j/2/). The problem is that this clears the very outer floating div.

Is there any way to clear a floated element without clearing another, outer floated element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to your `clear: both` style, add an `overflow: hidden` or `overflow: auto` style to `.MainRightCol` to give it its own [block formatting context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting):

```
.MainRightCol {
    background-color:#f5f5f5;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

This prevents the `clear: both` from clearing the `.MainLeftCol` float, [because](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#flow-control)

> The 'clear' property does not consider floats inside the element itself or in other [block formatting contexts.](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting)

and the context which `.MainLeftCol` lives in is `body`'s (or the viewport's, I'm not exactly sure), so that's outside of `.MainRightCol`'s and its `.ListItem` children's, which you apply the `clear` to.

See [the updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/bae2j/3).

Comment: That was fast! Thanks. I really don't yet understand why it works but will follow your links to better understand it.

Comment: Take your time! Floats are complicated little things.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you BoltClock! You have saved me from being carried off to the Asylum for the Incurably CSS Addled. This did the trick for me with a similar problem.

Comment: AAAAAAAAARGH!! I spoke too soon. Can anyone tell me why adding overflow:auto to the containers causes them to shrink? They're no longer taking up the full available width. http://jsfiddle.net/andfinally/wb4RE/

Comment: Found something about this on w3org http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#bfc-next-to-float, though I don't really get what they're on about. But removing the big left margin on my entry-container seemed to fix this weird shrinking. Why a container should shrink from the right when you give it a left margin is a complete mystery.